# Grabbing Mac OS clipboard information

Tags: macos, clipboard, copy-paste

I was surprised on just how complex it seems the clipboard is on a Mac (and I'm sure on other systems as well). For example, when copying something from Excel, the system clipboard has all the following 'variations':

[image]

How does it generate all the different 'types' on the left? Are those similar to a MIME-type, or what are all those listings there?

Comment: "How does it generate all the different 'types' on the left?" what "it" are you referring to? Excel, or the Clipboard Viewer?

Comment: The same _information_ can have multiple representations in a computer, for example if you copy a selection from a web-page then you've copied some HTML, but you can paste it as plain-text or RTF or as a HTML fragment, or as a link to the page you copied it from - which means the application that put data into the clipboard needs to provide all of those different representations, and that's what's listed on the left side.

Comment: Apple's documentation lists some (but not all) supported pasteboard types here: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nspasteboard/pasteboardtype

Comment: Everything you need to know is here: https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/PasteboardGuide106/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008099

Comment: @Dai actually I'm not sure. Does Excel generate all those different types on the left, or does Excel?

Comment: @Dai does for the example the Application (Chrome in the case of HTML) generate all those different copy clipboards, or does it just generate one and Mac figures all the different representations of it?

Comment: @David542 how do you get the window you show in your question? If I do Show Clipboard in the Finder I just get the clipboard contents with the type data at the bottom. The information in the grey on the left side isn't there.

Comment: @JimMerkel it took me forever to figure it out...I downloaded a file called `Additional_Tools_for_Xcode_11.dmg` from the Apple Developer site and inside it there is a Utility called "Clipboard Viewer".

Comment: @Dai would you want to post an answer with the relevant points here about the clipboard? The documentation you linked to are pretty heavy in Objective-C and I'm more interested in understanding the basics about it and not so much how to write a cocoa application that utlizes the clipboard.

Comment: @David542  Thanks, I hadn't seen those tools before. Lots of stuff in there to explore.